# Spring resource mapping issue on css

Tags: java, spring, jsp

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<resources mapping="/css/**" location="/resources/css/" />
<resources mapping="/swf/**" location="/resources/swf/" />
<resources mapping="/images/**" location="/resources/images/" />
```

Here is my resource mapping in Spring MVC Project. I successively loaded some images out at jsp. However, I can't load the background images in css using "../images/blah.png"
Any help or something please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was background tag problem.

```
background-image -> background
```